# How to get a row with most number of foreign keys in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Writer model/table and an Article model like:

```
class Writer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pic = models.URLField()
    start_date = models.DateField('date of start', blank=True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=300)

class Article(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

One Article can have only one Writer but One Writer can have many Articles.I can get all the writers with

```
Writer.objects.all()
```

But I want the Writer with most Articles. How can I do that?

Comment: `articles = Writer.objects.annotate(num_articles=Count('article')).order_by('-num_articles')`

Read about aggregation functions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
higest_count = Writer.objects.annotate(num_articles=Count('article')).order_by('-num_articles')[0].num_articles
print(higest_count) #this will print highest count
```

Answer (score 0):

> Returns an integer representing the number of objects in the database
>   matching the QuerySet. The count() method never raises exceptions.
>
> Example:
>
> Returns the total number ofentries in the database.

```
  Entry.objects.count()
```

> Returns the number of entries whose headline contains 'Lennon'

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains='Lennon').count()
```

With this count method in mind, you can count the related set of `Articles` by doing `Writer.article_set.count()`  and get the object with the most `articles`